# mongodb find $in, $gte and $lte

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, коллекции, запрос, meteor

имеется mongoDB и коллекции такого типа

```
{
_id: "CBopnqLivC4mPbcNZ"
cat: "NRB2uRdnnQXYGtg2W"
date: 1442742710650
desc: "text"
filters: [
  0: {
    name: ""
    url: "price"
    value: 3020
  },
  1: {
    name: ""
    url: "rat"
    value: 50
  }
  ..
  n:{
    name: "name",
    url : "other cat",
    value : "text"
  }
]
img: "img.png"
title: "title"
valuta: "usd"
}
```

меня интересует массив filters.
Делаю фильтр для товаров и проблема с range(интервалом), типо цены от 1000   до 2000, кроме range есть array.
Нужно сделать запрос который имел в себе интервал и обычный массив.

запрос на массив:

```
db.collection.find({'filters.value': { $in: ['Salmo','Dalmo'] }});
```

но, если использовать такой же запрос и для интервала, то цена должна совпадать =(

```
db.collection.find({
                    $and : [
                        { 'filters.value': { $in: ['Salmo','Dalmo'] } },
                        { 'filters.value': { $lte: 1000, $gte: 2000} }
                    ]
                });
```

нюанс в том, что в массиве много всего кроме цены filters.url == 'price'

Comment: что запросы ожидаемый результат? ппожалуйста, используйте [ссылку редактирования](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/452571/edit) чтобы показать ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 0: {
>   name: ""
>   url: "price"
>   value: 3020
> },
> 1: {
>   name: ""
>   url: "rat"
>   value: 50
> }
> ..
> n:{
>   name: "name",
>   url : "other cat",
>   value : "text"
> }
> ```

Предлагаю такую схему:

```
0: {
  name: ""
  "price": 3020
},
1: {
  name: ""
  "rat": 50
}
..
n:{
  name: "name",
  "other cat": "text"
}
```